# Discarded fragment layout being rendered on activity launch

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been working on my app for quite some time.
Now after doing some User Interface changes, when I launch my app the previous layout is being inflated which does not exist any more. I have tried rebuilding and cleaning the project even checking that I am using the correct resource id. I'm using Android Studio 1.0.2  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem, i deleted my gen folder then deleted my fragment layout created a new one then clean and rebuild. Thanks